# How to use Xcopy to download online files

Tags: file, download, xcopy

I've been trying to use Xcopy to download files from the internet but so far no luck. I was wondering if anyone has an idea of what i'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
    cd C:\AirlineSim\
echo Checking for Updates
xcopy /Y "http://interversesoftware.weebly.com/uploads/4/8/5/8/48585729/aspatcher.bat"
if /i not exist "ASpatcher.bat" (echo Could not retrieve update file.) && pause
if exist "ASpatcher.bat" call "ASpatcher.bat"
if exist "ASpatcher.bat" del "ASpatcher.bat"
goto menu
```

My Idea is that my file is for some reason blocked by Weebly so the program can't access it but that's all I can think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use xcopy to download a file from a http location. You could use wget for this. You can download wget for Windows from here:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

This website gives you some examples how to use it:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/